# ¿Cómo crear un variable PHP que muestre su resultado en varias páginas?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Al hacer clic en el botón ***"Enviar"*** de mi formulario, necesito crear una variable **$itemID**, su valor la añado desde mi Base de datos, dicha variable se debe mostrar en varias páginas (*recibido.php* y *1.php*) y este sea visto de inmediato después de presionar el botón de  **enviar**.

**Mi código actual:**

index.php

```
<?php
 session_start();
 ob_start();

 //Form Data
 include "../../includes/db_connect2.php";
 include "../../includes/db_connect_mysql.php";    

 //Recibo dato formulario.
 $codigo    = $_POST['codigo'];

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['codigo'])) {
      die('XXX!');
    }

   // veo Item ID des mi otra web
   $itemIDview = mssql_query('
   SELECT type, TypeID
   FROM PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items
   WHERE ItemID = \''.$codigo.'\'');

   $ItemIDvista = mssql_fetch_array($itemIDview);

   $itemIDvw = mysqli_query($conexion,'
   SELECT ItemName, ItemDesc
   FROM Items
   WHERE 
   Type = \''.$ItemIDvista[0].'\' 
   and
   TypeID = \''.$ItemIDvista[1].'\'');

   $ItemID = mysqli_fetch_array($itemIDvw);
   //$ItemID    = $_POST['ItemID'];
   //header("Location: 1.php"); 
   //exit; 

   $_SESSION['ItemName']=$ItemID['ItemName']; 
   echo '<a href="1.php">pagina</a>';
}
?>
<html>
<body>

   <h2>Agregar Items1</h2>

   <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">
     <table>
       <tr><td>ItemID:</td><td><input type="text" placeholder = "ItemID" name="codigo" /></td></tr>
     </table>       
     <p><input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="submit" /></p>
   </form>     

</body>
</html>
```

**Mostrar resultado:**

recibido.php o 1.php

```
<center>
   <textarea rows="30" cols="50">
     <?php
        session_start();
        ob_start();
        echo $_SESSION['ItemName'];
     ?>
   </textarea>
</center>
```

¿Cómo podría implementar dicho sistema en mi código actual?

Comment: Esta pregunta no está muy clara. ¿Dónde no recibes el valor? En el primer párrafo parece que quieres recibir la variable en 1.php pero en el último parece que lo quieres pasar a items.php. ¿Y recibes algún error?

Comment: Aparte de eso, el código que compartes parece vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL y no debería ser usado en entornos de producción. Te recomiendo que busques información sobre qué es la inyección SQL y cómo puede evitarse.

Answer (score 1):

En si respecto a tu código que tenías anteriormente publicado como ejemplo, habían algunos errores de sintaxis y era un poco caótico, te aconsejo que revises el [manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/index.php), para así orientarte mejor. También te aconsejo a utilizar [sentencias preparadas](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) para tener mayor seguridad en tu aplicación.

> **Advertencia:**
>   *mssql_query()*, esta función está OBSOLETA en PHP 7.0.0.

**Ejemplo como podría quedar:**

index.php

```
<?php 
  //Incluimos nuestro archivo item.php
  include 'items.php';

  //Página 1.php o alternativas, podrías trabajar mediante su sesión, igual que recibido.php
 ?>
<html>
<body>
  <h2>Agregar Items</h2>
  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
     itemID: <input type="text" placeholder = "itemid" name="codigo" />
     <input type="submit" value="Enviar" name="submit" />
  </form>

  <?php 
  if (isset($msg)) {
   echo "<div>$msg</div>";
  }
  ?>
</body>
</html>
```

items.php

```
<?php
session_start();//Arrancamos sesión.

//Reseteo variables.
$msg = $codigo = NULL;

//Si esta definida el formulario y no NULL.
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Comprobación campo vacio.
    if (empty($_POST['codigo'])) {
        //Mensaje de error.
        $msg = "El campo <b>Código</b> es obligatorio.";
    } else {        
        //incluir conexión (importante llamar cuando vaya a ser utilizado).
        include "../../includes/db_connect2.php";
        include "../../includes/db_connect_mysql.php";
        //Obtenemos dato, mas seguro.
        $codigo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion,$_POST['codigo'];
    }

    //verdadero
    if ($codigo) {

        //Sentencia
        $itemIDview = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT type, TypeID FROM PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items WHERE ItemID = '$codigo' LIMIT 1"); //Revisa bien los nombres de tu tabla, en este caso mi sublime text no me muestra correcto este nombre.

        //Comprobamos registros.
        if (mysqli_num_rows($itemIDview)===1) {
            if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($itemIDview)) {

                //extraemos datos sentencia '$itemIDview'.
                $tipo = $row['ItemName'];
                $tipoID = $row['ItemDesc'];

                //Segunda sentencia
                $itemIDvw = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT ItemName, ItemDesc FROM Items WHERE Type='$tipo'  AND TypeID = '$tipoID' LIMIT 1"); //revisa bien los nombres de tus campos, los mayusculas y minusculas deben estar tal cual. 

                //Comprobamos registros.
                if (mysqli_num_rows($itemIDvw)===1) {
                    if ($row_id = mysqli_fetch_array($itemIDvw)) {

                        //Creamos sesión para poder trabajar con ItemName y ItemDesc en diferentes páginas.
                        $_SESSION['ItemName'] = $row_id['ItemName'];
                        $_SESSION['ItemDesc'] = $row_id['ItemDesc'];
                        //Redirigimos a recibido.php
                        header('location:recibido.php');    
                    }
                }    
            }
        } else {
            //Mensaje de error.
            $msg = "0 registros encontrados en la Base de datos.";          
        }    
    }    
} mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

recibido.php o páginas alternativas

```
<?php
session_start();//Arrancamos sesión.

//Si esta definida las sesiones y no estan en NULL.
if (isset($_SESSION['ItemName']) && isset($_SESSION['ItemDesc'])) {   

    echo $_SESSION['ItemName'];
    echo $_SESSION['ItemDesc']; 

} else {
    //Podrías redirigir a index.php en caso que no exista la sesión.
    header('location:index.php');
}
?>
```

Comment: quite el positivo por que NO es conexion mySQL es MSSQL ose sql server  NO mysqli ni tampoco mysql es MSSQL osea SQL server  osea sql server 2008r2 o superior cual seria el lenguale equivalente? debe modificar su respuesta ya que fue la correcta pero en lenguaje equivocado

Comment: @JuanCarlosVillamizarAlvarez pienso que la pregunta si esta contestado **¿Cómo crear un variable PHP que muestre su resultado en varias páginas?** no tiene nada que ver con cómo usar `Microsoft SQL Server`, hace 4 años usabas `mssql_query()` **obsoleto** y te aconseje usar `mysqli_query` sobre el código con nos facilitaste en la pregunta. Para usar/emigrar a Microsoft SQL Server podrías mirar primero el manual y si tienes algún error o duda, crear una nueva pregunta. https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-connect.php

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el action de tu form en la primera página por el nombre de la segunda.

```
<form action="items.php" method="POST">
```

En tu segunda página obtienes el nombre con:

```
//verifica si la variable existe, el nombre es determinado por el name de tu input
if(isset($_POST['itemid'])) { 
  $itemId = $_POST['itemid'];
}
```

Ahora la variable $itemId vale lo enviado desde la primera página

Answer (score 0):

En item.php tienes el siguiente código:

```
$itemIDview = mssql_query('SELECT type, TypeID FROM PS_GameDefs.dbo.Items
WHERE ItemID = \''.$codigo.'\' ');
```

Donde `ItemID` tiene que ser lo que tenga el valor de `$codigo`.

Pero lo que veo es que en `item.php` no declaras `$codigo` y no le asignas ningún `valor`.

En cambio sí veo que `$código` está declarado y asignado en `index.php`.

> ¿De dónde sale `código`? ¿Viene de alguna otra página anterior? ¿Aún llamándose la primera `index.php`?

En la primera página (`index.php`) veo que tienes un formulario y un campo identificado como `itemid`. Por lo que tu problema, salvo error por mi parte, es que no estás logrando pasar el código que introduces en el formulario a la página `item.php`.

**¿Cómo pasar valores de una página a otra en php usando un formulario?**

1. La parte de asignar una referencia al campo está hecha. name=itemid.
2. En la página que recibe el dato incluye una variable que recoja el
   campo, para ello se crea la variable y se le asigna el valor de la
   referencia del campo.

   $nombre_variable = $_POST['itemid'];
3. Por último puedes usar $nombre_variable con el valor que haya introducido el usuario.

Por último indicarte que tu código es vulnerable a inyección sql. Te paso el siguiente enlace: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

Comment: Claro amigo pero si usted lee Codigo no viene de ninguna pagina anterior usted no esta notando el input dentro de index.php alli es donde lo ingreso manualmente

Comment: El código no viene de la página anterior, no explicas de donde lo sacas.

Comment: Al menos cuando he visto la pregunta esta mañana y mi respuesta se ha basado en lo que había esta mañana.

Comment: lo se men gracias pero su respuesta igual mente era casi valida y si habia declarado el valor $codido siempre estuvo declarado veras estuvo en la linea 10 en este Caso y no era un valor fijo el valo de Codigo provenia de un Input en todos los casos y ediciones gracias de igual manera

Answer (score 0):

Veo que has implementado el inicio de sesión con session_start(), por lo que yo usaría una variable $_SESSION[] que permanecería visible, sin importar desde qué página la requieras.

```
$_SESSION['itemID'] = (Aquí el valor que has recogido de tu Base de datos)
```

Luego, desde los respectivos formularios haces referencia a esta variable global de sesión incluyendo su valor mediante un campo oculto (hidden) para que pase a la siguiente instancia de tu programa.
La sentencia serí algo como esto:

```
<input type='hidden' name='itemID' value=' . $_SESSION["itemID"] . '>
```

Al hacer esto, cuando llegues a la página destino del formulario tendrás una variable $_POST['itemID'] con el valor mencionado, o bien, contarás con el mismo valor en la variable $_SESSION['itemID'] para otros eventuales usos.

Una vez que has terminado de utilizar la variable $_SESSION[] simplemente la eliminas de la memoria o la utilizas para almacenar el ID de otro item...

```
unset($_SESSION["itemID"]);
```